# Modify new tab behavior in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox

I have a Firefox extension (Toby for tabs) that hijacked the New Tab. Now the New Tab will display the extension's landing page no matter what.

There is no obvious way to disable this behavior without uninstalling the extension. For example, setting Home Page to Blank in Firefox preferences will still display the landing page for that extension.

Is there a way to disable this behavior without uninstalling the extension?

Firefox Quantum 57, OSX High Sierra

Comment: No. That's exactly how Toby is designed to work.

Comment: @DavidPostill So it is working at a deeper level than modifying some settings in about:config or similar?

Comment: It uses the new tab for it's configuration. You could ask the developers to change that behaviour.